# Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Let $$U(\alpha,\delta,z)=\frac{\Gamma(1-\delta)}{\Gamma(\alpha-\delta+1} {}_1\!F_1(\alpha,\delta,z) + z^{1-\delta}\frac{\Gamma(\delta-1)}{\Gamma(\delta)}\!F_1(\alpha-\delta+1, 2-\delta,z)$$
be the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function.
 the function $a\to U(a,1,z)$ is it holomorphic on $C$?

Comment: See http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/04/01/

Comment: Thanks a lot you. Have you other references?